# Topology diagram in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, diagram, topology

I have a web application which lets users create entities, and define relationships and associations between the entities.  I'd like to use silverlight to visually show a topology diagram of the entities.  Hopefully it would be able to have some smarts to figure out initial positions of each entity, and then potentially allow the user to move then entities around however they see fit.  Similar to how the database diagramming works in sql 2000 enterprise explorer.  Has this been done in silverlight, maybe something I can just re-use, or use as a sample to get me going.  Or even something I can port might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You could try save the topology (using on of the many tools to do so) as an image server side, the showing the image on the page.  This wouldn't require silverlight though.